# How to package an angular component along with all the dependent components and services in angular7 to use it in other angular apps

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on a app where i have developed a component which is displayed in router outlet and having other nested component inside it. Along with this it uses service of its own in ngOnInit() method to fetch the data from back end.
I want the this component to be packaged. So that it can be reused in another angular application without too much configurations.

Below is the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { RSService } from './details.service';
import { Term } from './Term';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'rs-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    terms: Term[];
    rowGroupMetadata: any;
    rowData: any;
    private sub: Subscription;

    constructor(private rsService: RSService, private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                const id = +params['id'];
                this.rsService.getRS(id).then(terms => {
                    this.terms = terms;
                    this.updateRowGroupMetaData();
                });
            });
        console.log('in Product details ngOnInit');
    }
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
        console.log('in ngOnDestroy');
    }
    updateRowGroupMetaData() {
      this.rowGroupMetadata = {};
      if (this.terms) {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.terms.length; i++) {
              this.rowData = this.terms[i];
              let SectionName = this.rowData.SectionName;
              if (i === 0) {
                  this.rowGroupMetadata[SectionName] = { index: 0, size: 1 };
              } else {
                  let previousRowData = this.terms[i - 1];
                  let previousRowGroup = previousRowData.SectionName;
                  if (SectionName === previousRowGroup) {
                    this.rowGroupMetadata[SectionName].size++;
                  } else {
                    this.rowGroupMetadata[SectionName] = { index: i, size: 1 };
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}





The goal is to reuse this component without much configuration in other angular application.
Anyone came across the same scenario please point me in right direction.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For packaging Angular components and re-use them in other Angular applications, you could use [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr). This even enables you to publish your library to the npm registry.
For further information just have a look at the documentation.